# Indexing lists with arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I want to index each element of a list using an array. For example, I want to use `list[arr] = 1`, where `arr` is an array instead of `list[ind] = 1` where `ind` is a number index. Using Dictionary data structure does the job, but creation of the dictionary is time consuming. Is there any other way I can do the above?

Comment: How is creating a dictionary more "time-consuming" than creating a list?  

Also, what do you mean by "array"?  Python has lists and tuples.  Did you want to use one of those as the key/index?

Comment: You can't. Lists are sequences, which use integer indices.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "creation of dictionary is time consuming"? Part of the reason it takes longer to create a `dict` than a `list` is the more flexible indexing it provides.

Comment: @MarkReed I have a list in which I need to access some elements directly and that depends on the some array (I use array and list interchangeably). The arrays I have do not have any natural order, so looking at the array I cannot tell what is the index of the element I want. To go about this I need a dictionary (which requires me to specify which array corresponds to which index) or label the list directly by the array.

Comment: "_and that depends on the some array_." I'm having trouble picturing your explanation. Can you provide code that replicates the problem you're having?

Comment: @chepner Time consuming in the sense that the number of possible arrays that I have to look at is very large. But I have already computed the list by other means.

Comment: @user2445465 Do not use "list" and "array" interchangeably. They are *not* the same thing.

Comment: @Kevin I compute an array, say [1,2,3,4]. Then I have to access the element number 5 in the list. And if the array were [2,3,6,1], then I have to access element number 9. There is no way I can 'derive' the element number just by looking at the array. I need to index the list by the array itself.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a step back and tell us what problem you're trying to solve rather than asking how to do this one specific, very odd thing.

Answer (score 0):

Pythons lists are really a variable length arrays of pointers and not a chain like one might initially think. So they do allow for random access in O(1) like what you are describing without the cost of a hash algorithm that a map has.

If you need to use pure arrays you're out of luck or need to extract it into module and do it in C.

Source: [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary with a tuple as the key:

```
mappings = { (1,2,3,4): 5, (2,3,6,1): 9 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to python.

Arrays can be tricky in python. As in most cases the term is not used. Probably because its an abstract concept. Just about anything in python can be an array. 
There are 4 basic types of arrays that I know of. strings, list, tuples, dictionaries. with that said. The following simple code could answer you question.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python


animals = ('cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'lion')

vehicle = ('car', 'truck', 'motorcycle')

fish = ('bass', 'trout', 'carp')


my_array = [ animals, vehicle, fish ]


print my_array[0]
print my_array[1]
print my_array[2]


>>> 
('cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'lion')
('car', 'truck', 'motorcycle')
('bass', 'trout', 'carp')
>>>
```